# How do I use perfect forwarding when writing template functions that wrap existing functions and check for errors?

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling

I'm wanting to wrap a number of function calls to an existing C library, which calls the function, checks if an error condition has been set, and then returns the value of the function, if any.  (Specifically, this is for OpenGl, but would work for legacy C functions as well.)  This is complicated by the fact that the functions may return void, which needs to be handled separately; and by the fact that I want to throw exceptions, which stops me from doing the check in the destructor of a guard object when it goes out of scope.

The following code basically works:

```
void check_for_error() {
// check and handle legacy error messages
// if (errno != 0)
// if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
//   throw std::runtime_error{"suitable error message"};
}

template <class R, class... Args>
using RvalFunc = R(*)(Args...);

// specialisation for funcs which return a value
template <class R, class... Args>
R exec_and_check(RvalFunc<R, Args...> func, Args... args) {
  R rval = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  check_for_error();
  return rval;
}

template <class... Args>
using VoidFunc = void(*)(Args...);

// specialisation for funcs which return void - don't store rval
template <class... Args>
void exec_and_check(VoidFunc<Args...> func, Args... args) {
  func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  check_for_error();
}
```

example usage:

```
exec_and_check(glBindBuffer, target, name);
FILE *pf = exec_and_check(fopen, "filename.txt", "rb");
```

...as opposed to...

```
glBindBuffer(target,name);
check_for_error();
FILE *pf = fopen("filename.txt", "rb");
check_for_error();
```

...where the checks might get missed, and which clutter up the code.  I'd prefer the `R exec_and_check(RvalFunc<R, Args...> func, Args... args)` to include a universal reference for forwarding (ie. `Args&&... args`), but that substitution causes a compilation error - Clang gives `note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Args' (<int, int> vs. <const int &, const int &>)`, as an example.

How would I modify this code to accept universal references?  Or have I missed something, and there's a much better way to error check legacy code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two template functions, which, as far as the compiler is concerned, differ only by return type.  To resolve this, you can use SFINAE as follows:

```
// specialisation for funcs which return a value
template <class R, class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<R>::value, R>
exec_and_check(RvalFunc<R, Args...> func, Args... args) {
  R rval = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  check_for_error();
  return rval;
}
```

and that fixes the problem (by preventing the above template function from matching when `R` is `void`).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QsVsSvcIJ0hdR1Nf)

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the problem - RvalFunc and VoidFunc are function arguments, and Clang is able to resolve them.  The problem I'm having is that I can't write `exec_and_check(RvalFunc<R, Args...> func, Args&&... args)` in order to get perfect forwarding, and which means certain arguments passed to these templates don't work as expected.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Interesting. gcc is not able to resolve them without the change suggested, I thought that was the problem. See also [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z0IPO9fUj0nQjDni) (please note the `Args&&` in both templates). Is that what you want?